# Does Catboost support python3?

Tags: python-3.x, yandex, catboost

I would like to use [`catboost`](https://github.com/catboost/catboost) project, that was recently released to open source community by Yandex. But, I use Python 3 in my projects. I know that Python 3 was prohibited by the Emperor of Yandex. Does `catboost` support Python 3?

Comment: https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/familyguy/images/1/1a/JointheEmpire.png/revision/latest?cb=20110122170121

Comment: Yes it supports. It's rebels' library.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can use `catboost` with Python 3 (and I'm personally already testing it). There is a correspondent wheels in PyPi:

```
catboost-0.1.1.2-py3-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
catboost-0.1.1.2-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
catboost-0.1.1.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: @monhawk i've tried to use these wheels you've mentioned to no avail on both MacOS and amazon's linux. The two are x64 architectures and  i've run `pip install wheel; pip install WHEEL_FILE`. The installation works but not the small classification task show in catboost's docs. Do these run correctly for you? Also, I've checked the correct platform and pep425tags were set by doing `import pip; print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())`.

Comment: @petobens I've tried on both Windows (10 + Anaconda with Python 3.6) and Linux (Fedora 26 with default Python 3), both works and I can run the examples.